# Custom compare function for sort() works without argument(c++)

Tags: c++

Why the custom compare function for sort() works without argument(c++)?

```
void show(int a[])
{
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }
}
bool compare(int a,int b)
{
    return a>b;
}
int main()
{
    int a[10]={12,32,45,22,643,53,53,32,4,32};
    sort(a,a+10,compare);
    show(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I see two arguments to the comparison function, as expected. They are called `a` and `b`, and both of them are `int`s.

Comment: You pass a pointer to the function, and then `std::sort` will call your function with the correct arguments.

Comment: compare is used by sort, it calls it with the arguments it needs. If you called it with arguments what arguments would you use?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't "work without arguments". You are passing `std::sort` a pointer to the function. `std::sort` will then call it (*with* arguments) as needed in order to sort the range.

Comment: it is working perfectly fine in code blocks.

Comment: @PrabalAggarwal You misunderstand. Yes, the code works - I never said it didn't. But your code is never calling the function with no arguments. `sort(a,a+10,compare);` is *not* calling the function. It's passing a function pointer. `std::sort` calls the function *through* that pointer internally and it *does* pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) function documentation, it says that the third argument to the function can either be a function pointer or a function object.

It is similar to the below code:

```
bool (*fPointer)(int, int) = compare; // Assign the function address to pointer
sort(a,a+10,fPointer);
```

We can even use the C++11 lambda function to do this job:

```
sort(a, a+10, [](int a, int b) { return a > b; } );
```